# Why does gdb report: "no debugging symbols found"?

Tags: gcc, gdb

I'm trying to build a debug version of unzip, edited makefile a bit, but gdb still say "no debugging symbols found". Example of make output:

```
gcc -c -O3 -Wall -DASM_CRC -g -I. -Ibzip2 -DUNIX   -DFUNZIP -o cryptf.o crypt.c
```

Maybe here is something wrong with flag order?

Comment: Shouldn't matter for that. Are you sure the binary's not stripped?

Comment: Check the `Makefile` again.  It's likely that `strip` is being invoked.

Comment: Yes, exactly, last line had -s at the end, thank you.

Comment: Not really advisable to use `-O3` if you want to debug.

Comment: gdb could be more verbose here.  A bug report wouldn't be amiss.  Meanwhile you can look for debug info like "readelf -WS $program | grep debug".  You should see at least a .debug_info section.